# SQL Concatenation Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a column called `I_Tags` and im trying to compare it to another table `Asset_Tags`.

`I_Tags` has fields like

```
PV-B02-0115
B04-PV-7126B--
B05-PV0841A--
B05-PV-0841B--
B09-PV-1155A--
```

Asset_Tags have fields like

```
PV-B04-6888
PV-B05-0841A--
PV-B05-1219
PV-B09-1155A--
```

Im unsure how to write a case statement based on the following scenarios:

1. If the first two characters in `I_Tag` are letters PV, match the entire string for matches with `Asset_Tags`
2. If not, and PV is 4th & 5th characters in `I_Tag`, move them to the 1st & 2nd character locations and remove any/all number of the dashes (-) at the end and match with `Asset_Tags`.

I have never written a case statement in SQL so Im unsure how to write a query for this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: can yo post the output

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: I havent tried case statement because I dont know where to begin  (Although I tried putting PV in one column, B05 etc in another, and last 4-6 characters in another and then concatinationg all based on Assets but that takes too long since data set is more than a few columns) the output for this is: PV-B05-0841A and PV-B09-1155A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps, if returns the result so that PV is always at the start and removes the trailing -s:

```
select
  case 
    when I_Tags like 'PV%' then I_Tags
    when I_Tags like '____PV%' then
      'PV-'+left(I_Tags, 3) + 
      substring(I_Tags, 7, len(I_Tags) -5 -patindex('%[^-]%', reverse(I_Tags)))
    end as test
from
  table1
```

You can test it in SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/526db/16

Not sure if there was a typo in your example with B05-PV0841A--, but it leaves it without the -.